# Arduino 101 - BLE Queries: Characteristics and Advertisement

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have the following queries regarding BLE peripheral on Arduino 101 :

1. Is is possible to advertise any characteristic value(dynamic data) rather than the UUID in the advertising packet. If so what are the APIs for that? My goal is to get any temperature data in the adv packet instead of connecting to the peripheral.

**Current Observation:** I was only able to advertise service uuids and local name using the APIs setAdvertisedServiceUuid and setLocalName.

2.In the following code I was able to start and capture the advertisement in the first instance but in the letter instance the begin had a false return value. Am I doing anything wrong? The idea is to start and stop the advertisement and may be even change the advertisement data.

```
#include <CurieBle.h>


void setup() {  
    // set LED pin to output mode
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {  
    //BLE Peripheral
    BLEPeripheral * blePeripheral = new BLEPeripheral; 

    //Set the Local Name
    blePeripheral->setLocalName("MyDevice");

    //Start Advertising
    blePeripheral->begin();

    //Run the advertisement for 20 seconds
    delay(20000);

    //Stop the advertisement
    blePeripheral->end();

    //Delete the BLE Peripheral
    delete blePeripheral;

    //Wait 5 seconds before starting the next adv
    delay(5000);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.
Swaroop

Answer (score 0):

```
BLEPeripheral blePeripheral;  // BLE Peripheral Device (the board you're programming)
BLEService ledService("19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214"); // BLE LED Service

// BLE LED Switch Characteristic - custom 128-bit UUID, read and writable by central
BLEUnsignedCharCharacteristic switchCharacteristic("19B10001-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);
```

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BLEPeripheralConstructor